# How to create a ros-dynamixel controller?

Tags: ros, arm-controller, dynamixel-controller

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am created an robotic 7-DOF arm using Robotis dynamixel servos. How can I able to control dynamixel servos from ROS. I am not find full documentation of it. Can any one help me.

Thanks in advanse

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/82146/how-to-create-a-ros-dynamixel-controller-?/) by [unais](https://answers.ros.org/users/4285/unais/) on ROS Answers with karma: 313 on 2013-09-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See the Dynamixel tutorials
http://wiki.ros.org/dynamixel_controllers/Tutorials

Also have a look at the code of CLAM Arm
http://correll.cs.colorado.edu/clam/

---

Originally posted by [achuwilson](https://answers.ros.org/users/1658/achuwilson/) with karma: 128 on 2013-09-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0